# web3.js or ethers.js, what should I learn in 2023?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, javascript

Just finished a quite old Udemy course where I used web3.js (solidity version was 0.4). I wish to bring myself up to date.

I heard nowadays, ethers.js became the norm. Is it true ? Or are they instances where web3.js is better ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **ethers.js** has gained popularity in recent years, especially with the rise of **Hardhat**, which uses **ethers.js** by default.

**Hardhat** offers many features that developers love, such as native **TypeScript** compatibility and **console.log** support.

**Ethers.js** is known for its **simplicity**, it is **easy to use**, and **smaller size**, which makes it **load faster compared to web3.js**.

Given its benefits and current trend, I would recommend learning ethers.js in 2023

Answer (score 0):

Go with **ethers.js**.

Check the npm package for [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers).

ethers became the most popular library by reaching 1 million+ weekly downloads, while [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) stills under 700K downloads.

Reasons:

1. Simple context.
2. Typescript support.
3. Easy to learn
4. The default library for **Hardhat** framework

Answer (score 0):

[web3.js](https://web3js.org) has just released a new version 4 which is more stable, less heavy and includes new features (like plugin builder, ENS, etc)

While ethers still have more downloads its because over the last 3 years, it became more stable and reliable than web3.js, but since this new release, web3.js has a stronger support team and is backed by the Ethereum foundation.